# Derivative of the complementary cdf

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

When you have a complementary cdf:

$$P(T>t) = 1- F(t)$$

Mathematically the following seems meaningful:

$$\frac{d (1-F(t))}{dt} = -\frac{d(F(t))}{dt} = p(t)$$

so

$$\frac{dP(T>t)}{dt} = -p(t)$$

where $p(t)$ is the probability density. Is the above correct?

Comment: The general idea is correct, yes, but this contains so many abuses of notation that one cannot validate it. F(T): Absurd. p(T=t): Not what you think. dP/dt: Undefined and absurd. p(T) the probability density: No.

Comment: What is wrong with the notation?

Comment: Which one? $ $ $ $

Comment: All of it $ $ $

Comment: The edit has somewhat improved the notation, but $p(T=t)$ still doesn't make sense; if $p$ is the probability density, you need $p(t)$ there.

Comment: Alternatively: $~p_T(t)~$.  Though, usually we use $f$ rather than $p$ for the density function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  Look up [Survival Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SurvivalFunction.html).